# Show that $\ker(C)=\{0\}$ - what is wrong with this arguement?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, functions, banach-spaces

Consider the operator $C:X\to X$ where $X=C([0,1])$ and $y\in X$ where $Cy(t)=\int_0^ty(\tau)d\tau+y(t)$. I want to show that $\ker(C)=\{0\}$. Here is my arguement, but I am not convinced that it is a very good one - what is wrong with it?

Suppose that, $$Cy(t)=0$$

$$\implies\int_0^ty(\tau)d\tau+y(t)=0$$
$$\implies\int_0^ty(\tau)d\tau=-y(t)$$
$$\implies\int_0^1\int_0^ty(\tau)d\tau dt=-\int_0^1y(t)dt $$
$$\implies\int_0^ty(\tau)d\tau=-\int_0^1y(t)dt$$

Now, the upper limit $t$ in the left integral is such that it must be from the interval $(0,1]$. Without loss of generality, suppose that this upper limit is $t=1$. Then,

$$\implies\int_0^1y(\tau)d\tau=-\int_0^1y(t)dt$$

$$\implies y(t)\equiv0,\,\forall \, t\in(0,1]$$

As $y(t)\equiv0$ is the only function that could satisfy this equality. What is wrong with this arguement? Is it valid? I have doubts that it is...

Comment: What happened to the first integral after your fourth arrow?

Comment: Note that $\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi \tau) d\tau =  - \int_0^1 \sin(2\pi t) dt = 0$, so the last implication is clearly false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are precisely two errors in your reasoning (each of which was separately observed in the comments on your question):

The first error is that the passage from $$\int_0^1\int_0^ty(\tau)d\tau dt=-\int_0^1y(t)dt $$ to
$$\int_0^ty(\tau)d\tau=-\int_0^1y(t)dt$$ is completely unjustified. (Why did you drop the $\int_0^1 ... dt$ on the left? Are you assuming the integrand ($\int_0^ty(\tau)d\tau$) is constant with respect to the variable $t$? It is not.)

The second error is that $$\int_0^1y(\tau)d\tau=-\int_0^1y(t)dt$$ only implies that $\int_0^1y(t)dt = 0$; it does not follow that $y$ is itself constantly $0$.

All the rest of your reasoning would have been sound, but each of these steps is unsupported and in fact fallacious.

Answer (score 0):

Arthur pointed out the main flaw in your argument. A possible argument goes like this. (thanks to Sridhar Ramesh for pointing out a mistake in *my* original argument)

The start of your argument is fine: take a function $y$ in Ker$(C)$, then
$$
\int_0^t y(\tau)d\tau = - y(t) .
$$
The left hand side of this equation is differentiable in $]0, 1[$, so the right hand side must also be differentiable in $]0, 1[$. Taking the derivative with respect to $t$ on both sides yields
$$
y(t) = -y'(t)
$$
for all $t \in ]0, 1[$. Recall from an elementary course in differential equations that the solutions to this equation are exactly of the form
$$
y(t) = Ke^{-t} \quad K \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
So the only possible elements of Ker$(C)$ must be of the form $Ke^{-t}$. On the other hand, if we plug in such a function into $C$ we get
$$
Cy(t) = \int_0^t K e^{-\tau}d\tau + Ke^{-t} = K(1 - e^{-t}) + Ke^{-t} = K
$$
which is $0$ if and only if $K = 0$. Hence, Ker$(C)$ = $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Comment: You've correctly shown that every element of the kernel is of the form $Ke^{-t}$, but not the converse that every function of this form in fact falls in the kernel. For $K \neq 0$, these will not; consider that when we take the integral $\int_{0}^{t} y(\tau) d\tau$, we must choose the particular antiderivative which vanishes at $t = 0$. This will turn out to cause $\int_{0}^{t} y(\tau) + y(t) = -K$.

In other words, what led you astray is that when you differentiate the original equation, you introduce spurious solutions which only satisfy the original equation up to an additive constant.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't quite awake enough! Thanks a lot and my apologies if I have confused OP.

Comment: How is it that you know that the left hand side is differentiable for $t\in]0,1[$? As we are working in $C([0,1])$ I would never have thought to consider $t\in]0,1[$.

Comment: The left hand side is differentiable because $y$ is continuous; look up the fundamental theorem of calculus in your notes. The reason I restricted to $]0,1[$ is because differentiability is not defined in the endpoints of an interval. Nevertheless, by the continuity of $y$, we know $y$ on $[0,1]$ once we know $y$ on $]0,1[$.